# How to add up all relevant data in a VLOOKUP type way

Tags: excel

[Current Excel Document I'm working on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V11wJ.jpg) I'm building an excel document that helps me keep track of my investment portfolio. I have an array that's dedicated to all my trading activity (in the relevant photo, the array is column I through N). In column B I've extracted all the unique values from column J and have sorted them alphabetically (these are the stock tickers). What I'm looking to do is list the total number of shares I've accumulated for each stock in column C. This should also be dynamic as I continue my trading history in the array. Because I'm often buying and selling the same stock multiple times, I've listed whether I bought or sold the stock in column K. As an example of the outcome I'd like, I'd like cell C4 to add up all the shares I've bought for each stock, then minus all the shares I've sold of that stock using the data from the array.  Not sure how to do this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The list in column B can be dynamic if you use a pivot table. No formula required.

Turn the range in columns I to N into an Excel Table object with Insert > Table or Ctrl-T. Then add a column to that table for the share count, with the formula

```
=IF([@action]="buy",[@shares],[@shares]*-1)
```

Now you simply insert a pivot table into cell B2. Drag Stock into the row field well and Sharecount into the values field well.

[image]

When new data is added to the data source table, refresh the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

The `SUMIFS` function can perform this exactly. Enter the following in `C3` and drag down to the bottom of your list of ticker symbols. This will update automatically whenever a new buy or sell row is added.

```
=SUMIFS(L:L,J:J,"="&B3,K:K,"=Buy")-SUMIFS(L:L,J:J,"="&B3,K:K,"=Sell")
```